# Is it a better way to loop thru range of variables?

Tags: c#

Consider a simple equation: 5 = 2 * a + 4 * b - 3 * c

Is it a better way to loop thru the variables than multiple for loops?

This has multiple answers, but in order to find answers to the equation I'm using multiple for loops like

```
for(int a = 1; a < 50; a++) {
  for(int b = 1; b < 50; b++) {
    for(int c = 1; c < 50; c++) {
      //validate
    }
  }
}
```

Now, for this example this would not take much time. But if this was going thru a dataset of thousands of entries and the goal of the for loop is see If I can find a optimized set of variables then its going to take some time. Maybe there are more than 3. The equation above is just an example.

Is there a alternative better way to do this? A code pattern maybe? I'm also interested to see how I can clean this up as there is a lot of nesting.

My validation logic is already thrown inside a BackgroundWorker and I limit the count so I can utilize 100% of the CPU, so I'm mainly looking into not doing for-loop nesting if possible.

Comment: I think this can be solved using matrices instead of loops.

Comment: The matrices method of solving linear equations has been discussed in [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/673076/Linear-Equation-Solver-in-Csharp).

Comment: You don't need the most inner loop. Just calculate it like `c = (2 * a + 4 * b - 5) / 3` and the complexity becomes O(AxB) instead of O(AxBxC)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nested loop is the most efficient way to do it, and you can parallelize it pretty easily by [`Parallel.For`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for)ing the outer loop.

```
int solutionsCount = 0;
Parallel.For(1, 50, a =>
{
    for (int b = 1; b < 50; b++)
        for (int c = 1; c < 50; c++)
            if (2 * a + 4 * b - 3 * c == 0) Interlocked.Increment(ref solutionsCount);
});
```

If you want to get fancy you can create a custom iterator that will produce all the permutations:

```
private static IEnumerable<(int a, int b, int c)> Loop(int to1, int to2, int to3)
{
    for (int a = 1; a < to1; a++)
        for (int b = 1; b < to2; b++)
            for (int c = 1; c < to3; c++)
                yield return (a, b, c); // this is a ValueTuple<int, int, int>
}
```

And use it like this:

```
foreach (var p in Loop(50, 50, 50))
{
    // Do something with p.a, p.b and p.c
}
```

You can even use LINQ to get the solutions directly:

```
var solutions = Loop(50, 50, 50)
.Where(p => 2 * p.a + 4 * p.b - 3 * p.c == 0);
Console.WriteLine($"Solutions: {String.Join(", ", solutions)}");
```

...but it is 10 times slower.

You could even go pure LINQ like this:

```
var solutions = Enumerable.Range(1, 50 - 1)
.SelectMany(a => Enumerable.Range(1, 50 - 1)
.SelectMany(b => Enumerable.Range(1, 50 - 1)
.Where(c => 2 * a + 4 * b - 3 * c == 0)));
```

...which has about the same performance as the previous one. It is also parallelizable by chaining [`AsParallel()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.parallelenumerable.asparallel) in the query (after the first `Enumerable.Range`).